# Delete dynamically adding table row with Jquery but unable to save the varibale value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am add table row dynamically on button.click event.

If i use this code delete row is not functioning.

```
var count = 1;
$('button[id^="product"]').click(function () {
//adding row to table : WORKING FINE

count++;         
});

$(".del_row").click(function() {
//removing row // NOT WORKING
count--;
});
```

If i try code bwloe. It is working but the count goes back to 0; and - on 2nd click :(

```
$('button[id^="product"]').click(function () {
//adding row to table : WORKING FINE
count++;
$(".del_row").click(function() {
//removing row 
count--;
});     

});
```

Comment: `.click` doesnot work for dynamic insertions. you should use `.on`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#TABLE_ID").on("click", ".del_row", function() {
   //remove row here
   count--;
});
```